# Opening google sheet API 4 from JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, google-sheets-api

As per the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java
I'm supposed to download a client_secret.json and place it in the root directory, this json will be used for authentication.

```
/** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
    System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

/** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

/** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 *
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
 * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
```

I'm not sure if it is being read correctly, the authentication fails everytime.
Usually in a Java SE application there would be a message in the console with a one time google URL, opening that URL will authenticate the application and enable it to access google sheets.
This is not happening in this Java EE application. I'm not even sure if Java EE is reading the json file (it failed to read a test text file from the same location).
How can I have Java EE read the json file and authenticate with google sheets?

Comment: @BalusC would you be able to help?

Comment: The instructions ask you to put it in the `src/main/resources` folder, are you doing that?